# What causes version of NiFi component to update?

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-minifi

While creating a NiFi flow I'm realizing the versions of the components changing.

I understand that the version changes each time the component updates - but what is considered an update of a component?

For example, what causes an update in a connection's version?

I'm trying to find some pattern but with not much luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The [official documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#component-versioning) states that you can have multiple versions of your flow at the same time:

> You have access to information about the version of your Processors, Controller Services, and Reporting Tasks. This is especially useful when you are working within a clustered environment with multiple NiFi instances running different versions of a component or if you have upgraded to a newer version of a processor.

You can opt-out of versioning all together:

**Methods of disable the versioning:**

1. **NiFi UI:** To change the version of a flow, right-click on the versioned process group and select `Version`→`Change version` [*(link)*](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#stop-version-control).
2. **Rest API:** Send an http `DELETE` request to `/versions/process-groups/{id}` with the appropriate `ID`.

You can also use **Toolkit CLI** to view available versions, by executing `./bin/cli.sh registry diff-flow-versions` [*(link)*](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/toolkit-guide.html#nifi_CLI).